# How are Keybase group chats encrypted?

Tags: instant-messaging, end-to-end-encryption, keybase

Keybase co-founder Chris Coyne: "Our goal is end-to-end encryption with minimal friction".  How does Keybase do this for Keybase group chats?

It relates to this question: [Which protocols exist for end-to-end encrypted group chat?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126768/which-protocols-exist-for-end-to-end-encrypted-group-chat)

I haven't found the answer in the [Keybase docs](https://keybase.io/docs/chat/crypto).

Comment: I'll try.. https://keybase.io/docs/teams/crypto

Comment: It is a bit cryptic and can't say I understand all of it, but I think I get the basics.. :)

Comment: If the answer is in the documentation, and you were looking up the wrong documentation, then a link is useful, but then the link itself is not a great answer. So if someone can include the relevant parts of the link in an answer, then that's the answer that should be posted.